# Flutter: How to pick files with filter extensions in any directory?

Tags: flutter, filepicker.io, filepicker

How to pick file with any extensions using of **file_picker** package​. And filter with customize paramater extensions even if I open any directory.

Currently, it's working in case the first open. but when I change to other directory it still show files that I don't want.

Please you help to advice me how can I acheive this case.
Thank you.

Example:
When browse files by filter .pdf
[image]
When I choose Gallery.
[image].
Show .jpg extension. Filter .pdf is not working
[image]

```
Future<void> loadFiles(List<String> extensions) async {
    try {
      var platformFiles = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowMultiple: true, allowedExtensions: extensions);
      if (platformFiles != null) {
        files.value = platformFiles.files;
        Get.to(() => const ConverterScreen());
      }
    } catch {
      print("[ERROR]${e.toString}");
    }
  }
```

Comment: is it shows you the previous selected files.?

Comment: Hello @AhmadEllamey
By default using this package It will direct Dowload Folder right?
In this directory the filter extension is working but when I select the drawer and choose Gallery then it shows image file PNG, JPG with enable select.. even if I filter [.pdf]

Comment: i think if you click add it will dispose without adding the file , but the gallery show all , i will see why and tell you.

Comment: It's not dispose brother. I already tested.
I still can add those files.